# Write a function where the input of string returns a list. Elements should not have leading or trailing spaces and sorted in ascending order

Tags: python

my current code is

```
def location_list(checkins):
    """ takes input of check in and return the locations from the given checkins"""
    checks=str(checkins)
    final=[]
    for elem in checks:
        final.extend(elem.strip().split(';'))
    return final
```

and result i am getting is

```
checkins = '(33.63, -111.92);   (33.34, -111.88);     (33.57, -111.93);     (33.26, -111.88);(33.55, -111.93)'
print(location_list(checkins))

['(', '3', '3', '.', '6', '3', ',', '', '-', '1', '1', '1', '.', '9', '2', ')', '', '', '', '', '', '(', '3', '3', '.', '3', '4', ',', '', '-', '1', '1', '1', '.', '8', '8', ')', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '(', '3', '3', '.', '5', '7', ',', '', '-', '1', '1', '1', '.', '9', '3', ')', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '(', '3', '3', '.', '2', '6', ',', '', '-', '1', '1', '1', '.', '8', '8', ')', '', '', '(', '3', '3', '.', '5', '5', ',', '', '-', '1', '1', '1', '.', '9', '3', ')']
```

while the correct outcome should be

```
checkins = '(33.63, -111.92);   (33.34, -111.88);     (33.57, -111.93);     (33.26, -111.88);(33.55, -111.93)'
print(location_list(checkins))

['(33.26, -111.88)', '(33.34, -111.88)', '(33.55, -111.93)', '(33.57, -111.93)', '(33.63, -111.92)']
```

Comment: I think based on stack overflow's guidelines for a functionnal QA website, your title should be more concise, and make some sense without reading the post.

Comment: @JohnColeman `append` makes it look even worse.

Comment: sorry new to coding and stackoverflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do it.. your issue is that you are iterating over each character in the string.

```py
def location_list(checkins):
    """ takes input of check in and return the locations from the given checkins"""
    checks=str(checkins)
    final = [x.strip() for x in checks.split(';')]
    return final


checkins = '(33.63, -111.92);   (33.34, -111.88);     (33.57, -111.93);     (33.26, -111.88);(33.55, -111.93)'
print(location_list(checkins))

['(33.63, -111.92)', '(33.34, -111.88)', '(33.57, -111.93)', '(33.26, -111.88)', '(33.55, -111.93)']
```

I'm not sure what values you want to sort on, but you will need to parse the `final` list items to get the values and sort.

Comment: Look at OP's output, doesn't it differ?

Comment: OP wanted the output be in ascending order.

Answer (score 1):

Use list comprehension to build the resulted list and use `sorted` to sort it -

```
def location_list(checkins):
    """ takes input of check in and return the locations from the given checkins"""
    checks = str(checkins)

    final = [x.strip() for x in checks.split(';')]   
    return sorted(final)

checkins = '(33.63, -111.92);   (33.34, -111.88);     (33.57, -111.93);     (33.26, -111.88);(33.55, -111.93)'
print(location_list(checkins))
```

Result:

```
['(33.26, -111.88)', '(33.34, -111.88)', '(33.55, -111.93)', '(33.57, -111.93)', '(33.63, -111.92)']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution that returns correct outcome you expect. I added comments to explain what I attempted to do in each process:

```py
checkins = '(33.63, -111.92);   (33.34, -111.88);     (33.57, -111.93);     (33.26, -111.88);(33.55, -111.93)'

# This line removes ; from the string
checkins = checkins.replace(";", "")
>>> "(33.63, -111.92)   (33.34, -111.88)     (33.57, -111.93)     (33.26, -111.88)(33.55, -111.93)"

# This line splits all the info beginning with (
checkins = checkins.split("(")
>>> ['', '33.63, -111.92)   ', '33.34, -111.88)     ', '33.57, -111.93)     ', '33.26, -111.88)', '33.55, -111.93)']

# This variable holds the correct format of checkins
formatted = []

for checkin in checkins:
    # if the value is not empty
    if checkin:
        # Since you want strings, ( and ) are added back as string.
        formatted.append("("+checkin.replace(")", "").strip()+")")
        
# sorts the list inplace
formatted.sort()

print(formatted)
>>> ['(33.26, -111.88)', '(33.34, -111.88)', '(33.55, -111.93)', '(33.57, -111.93)', '(33.63, -111.92)']
```